# Pointers as function arguments when implementing a structure

Tags: pointers, rust

Why there is a `&` symbol before `self` in the `full_name()` function but there isn't any in the `to_tuple()` function? When I look at them, the usage of `self` is similar in both function, but why use `&`. Also when I add `&` to `to_tuple()` or delete it from `full_name()` it would throw an error. Can someone explain it?

```
fn full_name(&self) -> String {
    format!("{} {}", self.first_name, self.last_name)
}

fn to_tuple(self) -> (String, String) {
    (self.first_name, self.last_name)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`full_name` does not consume `self`, it uses a reference via `&self`: The members are only used via references as arguments to `format!()`, so a reference suffices.

`to_tuple` (as the name `to_...` suggests) consumes `self`: It moves the members from `self` into the returned tuple. Since the original `self` is no longer valid memory after the move (`self` no longer owns the memory), it has to be consumed, hence a move via `self`.

You can change `full_name` to use `self`, that is move ownership. This would become unhandy, though, as calling the function would consume the struct without the need to.

`to_tuple` could be changed to not consume `self`, yet it would need to `.clone()` (make a copy) of the members, which is costly.

Comment: The `to_` prefix [does have a semi-official meaning as a *non*-consuming ad-hoc conversion, like `Path::to_str` and `str::to_lowercase`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html#ad-hoc-conversions-follow-as_-to_-into_-conventions-c-conv); the conventional name for a `self`-consuming function would be `into_tuple`.